# VBA: How do you handle passing Sheet2!A:A through function parameters?

Tags: excel, vba, function, parameters

So I'm aware that Sheets2!A:A Refers specifically to the whole of column A within the Sheet 2 workbook.
However, how do you actually process this when it's passed through a function?

```
Function Function1(cellValue As Variant, cellList As Range) As Variant
Dim cellContent As Variant
Dim list As Range
Dim i As Integer
cellContent = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(CStr(cellValue)).Value2
list = Range(cellList).Value2
For i = 1 To list
    If i = cellContent Then
        Function1 = "Found"
    Else
        Function1 = "Unfound"
    End If
Next i
```

End Function

How would you parse Sheets2!A:A so that it uses the sheet specified and then the range of values in A:A.
I'm using a function so therefore it's effectively being passed through by the user as

```
=@Function1(A2,Sheet2!A:A)
```

Comment: The second argument of your function should be a `Range` object, that you can just use as necessary (although it's inefficient to use entire columns generally).

Comment: please [edit] the question to include a [mcve].  This should include a function that represents how you are declaring the  variables and represent what you are trying to do with those variables.

Comment: @ScottCraner This works if you manually change the values. However, if the user uses the function instead with =Function1(A5, Sheets2!B:B) Then how would I do this automatically?

Comment: @ScottCraner Apologies, I have edited with an example of what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the range is already a range:

```
Function Function1(cellValue As range, cellList As Range) As Variant
Dim cellContent As Variant
Dim list As Variant
Dim i As Long
cellContent = cellvalue.Value2
list = intersect(cellList.parent.usedrange,celllist).Value2
Function1 = "Unfound"
For i = 1 To ubound(list,1)
    If list(i,1) = cellContent Then
        Function1 = "Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

---

But this just reinvents MATCH:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"Found","Unfound")
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, this worked perfectly! I'll have to read up on Intersect and Ubound, as I've never seen that before

Comment: @Eynos please consider marking as correct.  Intersect allows us only to loop what is used and not the full column, saving some comp time.  Ubound() returns the number of items in the variant array we create.